# Obtener String de array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Tengo este array que le añado objetos:

```
waypts.push({location: location.lat() + "," + location.lng()});
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor literal que guarda?
Con `Object.value` y `valueOf` no me hace lo que pretendo

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quiere obtener?

Comment: Quiero obtener el string que hay dentro del campo location. El ejemplo de arriba es la manera en la que añado elementos al array del que quiero sacar esa informacion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creo que lo más limpio sería utilizar [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map):

```js
waypts = [{location:"32.34,75.34"}]
waypts.push({location: "48.68" + "," + "92.34"});

var names = waypts.map(function(item) {
  return item['location'];
});

console.log(names[0]);
console.log(names[1]);
console.log(waypts[0].location);
console.log(waypts[1].location);
```

**Edito**:
Tras el comentario de @LPZadkiel dejo su solución aquí para que sea más visible. Puedes acceder directamente a la propiedad location del objeto así:

```
waypts[0].location
```

Comment: Vale gracias por la ayuda, funciona a la perfección.

Comment: pero pudo simple y sencillamente hacer `waypts[0].location` que tiene mejor performance que usar map

Comment: Cierto, también es muy buena opción. Quizás nos faltaría saber un poco más sobre el contexto en el que se va a usar.